# Как выключить модуль bitrix через FTP?

Tags: php, битрикс, php7

В результате перехода на php пытался поймать ошибку, почему не выводилась главная. В административной панели включил вывод всех ошибок и получил это:

```
    [ErrorException] E_DEPRECATED
Non-static method CSecurityAntiVirus::OnPageStart() should not be called statically (0)
/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/module.php:490
#0: ExecuteModuleEventEx(array)
    /home/bitrix/ext_www/host.svarbi.ru/bitrix/modules/main/include.php:304
#1: require_once(string)
    /bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_admin_before.php:18
#2: require_once(string)
    /bitrix/modules/main/interface/desktop.php:2
#3: require(string)
    /home/bitrix/ext_www/host.svarbi.ru/bitrix/admin/index.php:2
```

Теперь мне нужно восстановить работоспособность и отключить вывод ошибок в модуле main bitrix 16.5.11 при помощи php. Знаю в Wordpress можно сделать достаточно просто, но не могу найти аналогичные действия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выключить модуль непосредственно через ftp нельзя. Вы можете загрузить какой-то скрипт, который будет удалять модуль.

Управлять выводом ошибок через htaccess не достаточно. Т.к. битрикс в главном модуле переопределяет вывод ошибок (есть настройка `/bitrix/admin/settings.php?lang=ru&mid=main&mid_menu=1`).

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете отключить ошибки в файле .htaccess или в базе данных в таблице b_option